# Bad request error from MySQL database on filtering text column for special characters '=','<' and '>'

Tags: mysql, database, request, escaping, character

I want to filter a field of type mediumtext for the equal sign. But that throws a 400 Bad Request error. I get the same result when I filter for the greater-than or smaller-than sign. I guess because these symbols conflict with the SQL comparison operators. I am making a request to MySQL Maria database via the dreamfactory’s API.

I tried escaping the equal sign with a backslash, but it did not work.

How can I distinguish between the equal sign the 'filter=' and the equal sign in 'myColName like %=%' ?

Any ideas are welcome :)

Details:
Request URL:

> …/mytablename?fields=content&filter=content%20like%20%25%3D%25

Response Body:

```
{
“error”: {
“code”: 400,
“context”: null,
“message”: “Invalid or unparsable field in filter request: ‘content like %’”,
“status_code”: 400
}
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/paulochf/f5cf65fe9049676cfc86

Comment: Hey soft87, thanks for the quick response. Could you explain what exactly you would do with the urldecoder function?
I imagine you would have dreamfactory run that function on reception of an API call. Though I would prefer not to at any extra code to dreamfactory. I can't believe that you can't do it with the regular dreamfactory API.